# Remove cid variable from URL in jsf

Tags: jsf, seam

I am using JSF and want to remove/hide cid variable from url which is getting appended in url ?
ex. https://1.2.3.4/login.xhtml?cid=33

Comment: "which is getting appended" how?

Comment: cid(converstation id)  just comes with using Seam, especially when doing redirects.

Comment: So did you do something like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=seam+adds+conversation+id+to+url)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disabling seam's redirect filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431652/disabling-seams-redirect-filter)

Comment: And one of the first links is (imo) a duplicate SO post!... less then 5 minutes searching ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just create a html-link using a relative URL:

```
<a href="../../login.xhtml">Login</a>
```

Basically, JSF adds the conversation scope id to outcomes, but not to html URLs.

If you need an absolute URL (i.e., without relative navigation like `../../`), base it on the URL pointing to your JSF web application:

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/login.xhtml">Login</a>
```

Comment: In this case it is a jsf version that has no conversation scope knowledge, but it is done by 'seam'.